# Knowledge of jenkins is required to learn robot framework?

Tags: python-3.x, jenkins, robotframework

Is there knowledge of jenkins is required to learn robot framework

Comment: If you follow some examples in the robot framework user guide you'll see that you can run robot on your own computer.

Comment: No. I use RF for several years and don't even really know what Jenkins is. I'm not even sure we use Jenkins in my company.

Answer (score 1):

No Jenkins knowledge is not required unless you want to run your tests on Jenkins which is still independent of any test framework like robot.

Comment: But if I want to practice robot framework? Is knowledge required?

Comment: you can practice it on your system itself initially once done you can move towards using  the jenkis plugin. user guide at http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html